# Second conditional or past real conditional?

Tags: conditionals, past-perfect, perfect-aspect, sequence-of-tenses

There is this quote from the show *Cosmos: A Spacetime Odyssey* that confuses me:

> If it wasn't for Edmond Halley, Newton's great book would've never been conceived, nor written, nor printed.

Now I understand that the contruction "If+past tense" can sometimes be used to talk about a past real conditional, but it doesn't seem logical here. So is the first half second conditional? If so, why isn't it better to use third conditional since it's a hypothetical scenario of a past event or is there some other explanation here?

Comment: What you're taught in ESL class doesn't really reflect how English works: the various types of conditionals are a simplification of the actual language. It's very common to use ["If it wasn't"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/if-it-wasn-t-weren-t-for) instead of "If it hadn't been". (Questions about types of conditional probably belong on English Language Learners.)

Comment: According to [this site](https://promova.com/english-grammar/second-conditional-in-english) second conditional is a hypothetical present or future. When talking about the past, "If it wasn't" is a counter-factual.